# combining two varchar fields in same SELECT statement without merging values

Tags: mysql

The SQL query in my PHP file is

```
SELECT start_time,end_time FROM data;
```

This returns the two varchar fields in two different columns. Now i wish to combine these. So I tried

```
Select start_time+' '+end_time as time from data;
```

This returns some numeric value. So I tried:

```
Select cast(start_time+' '+end_time) as time from data;
```

If the data in my table is 
start_time = 8:00 a.m 
end_time = 9:30 a.m

how can I display 8:00 a.m - 9:30 a.m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select CONCAT(start_time, ' - ', end_time) as time FROM data
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
SELECT CONCAT(start_time, ' ', end_time) AS time FROM data;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(start_time,' ',end_time) as time FROM TEBLENAME
```